# How do I resize a disk image device?

Tags: dd, ntfs, ntfs-3g, ddrescue

I'm trying to reduce the size of a backup drive image.  Original disk had these partitions:

```
Model: ST916082 1A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 160GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  65.7GB  65.7GB  primary   ntfs         boot
 2      65.7GB  160GB   94.4GB  extended               lba
 5      65.7GB  160GB   94.4GB  logical   ntfs
```

Image was created from the logical partition using the command

```
> sudo ddrescue /dev/sde5 datapartition logfile

Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Initial status (read from logfile)
rescued:         0 B,  errsize:       0 B,  errors:       0
Current status
rescued:    94368 MB,  errsize:       0 B,  current rate:   23068 kB/s
   ipos:    94368 MB,   errors:       0,    average rate:   28839 kB/s
   opos:    94368 MB,     time from last successful read:       0 s
Finished
```

`ntfsresize -i -f datapartition` says:

```
ntfsresize v2012.1.15AR.5 (libntfs-3g)
Device name        : datapartition
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size       : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 26999992832 bytes (27000 MB)
Current device size: 94368605184 bytes (94369 MB)
Checking filesystem consistency ...
100.00 percent completed
Accounting clusters ...
Space in use       : 26107 MB (96.7%)
Collecting resizing constraints ...
You might resize at 26106810368 bytes or 26107 MB (freeing 893 MB).
Please make a test run using both the -n and -s options before real resizing!
```

So it looks like I already resized the filesystem to fit the data, but did not resize the device?  (This was 2 years ago, I forget.)  And I need to resize the device using fdisk, right?  But fdisk doesn't recognize the partition:

```
> fdisk -lu datapartition 

Disk datapartition: 94.4 GB, 94368605184 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 11472 cylinders, total 184313682 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x69205244

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
datapartition1   ?   218129509  1920119918   850995205   72  Unknown
datapartition2   ?   729050177  1273024900   271987362   74  Unknown
datapartition3   ?   168653938   168653938           0   65  Novell Netware 386
datapartition4      2692939776  2692991410       25817+   0  Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

nor does cfdisk:

```
> cfdisk datapartition 

FATAL ERROR: Bad primary partition 1: Partition begins after end-of-disk
                      Press any key to exit cfdisk
```

I can mount the partition and copy files off of it, though.  How do I resize the device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's just the dump of the partition, there's no partition table. The partition is the file, you just need to shrink the file:

```
truncate -s 27000832000 datapartition
```

(27000832000 is 26999992832 rounded up to the next MiB just to be on the safe side, would you like for instance to compress it to a `qcow2` format or any other mountable compressed format)

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense.  Before I actually do it, though, can  you provide a reference or a little more reassurance that there's no useful information in the part of the file I'm truncating?

Comment: @endolith, if in doubt, you can always do a `losetup -r --sizelimit=27000832000 /dev/loop0 datapartition` and check that that `loop0` is OK (set the sizelimit to 26900832000, and you'll see you can't mount it).

Comment: Confirmed that `sudo mount -o loop /dev/loop0` does not work with losetup 26900832000 but does work with 27000832000.  Also found a note to myself that the partition originally only had 25 GB of data on it, so I truncated it and it still mounts correctly.  Yay free space!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) a look. We usually use this live distro when we want to resize partitions of varying types.

#### sample screenshots of gparted

[image: ss of gparted #1]

[image: ss of gparted #2]

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html) for further details.

Comment: But here, there's no partition table to adjust.