# how do I shrink a partition, right after shrinking its filesystem with resize2fs?

Tags: filesystems, partition, fdisk, parted, resize2fs

This is what've done to shrink `/home` partition filesystem:

```
e2fsck /dev/sda1

resize2fs /dev/sda1 150G
```

As of now, if I run `df` it is going to show me that the partition has shrunk from 210G to 150G (which is [not true](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/130651/435414)).

Since I've only reduced filesystem size, how can I shrink the partition size using `fdisk` or `parted`?

Comment: Was /home mounted whilst you reduced its file system size? What does the man page for parted say about changing partition size?

Comment: @JeremyBoden it was not mounted. I've rebooted my computer, kepts pressing SHIFT and used Lubuntu advanced settings in order to boot as root. After that I've proceeded to use mentioned commands.

Comment: I understand your concern about me not reading man page, but I'm too afraid to risk doing it by myself because I don't have an installation disk with me right now, if anything goes wrong.

Comment: df doesn't report the partition size. It reports the filesystem size, which you shrank to 150G. To shrink a partition, the best tool is probably gparted. However, if the data in that filesystem has any value, I recommend taking a backup first, because it is easy to break things.

Comment: If you had used gparted - a GUI program, it would have resized your file system (if safe to do so) **and** resized your partition. It would still be recommended, in a view-only mode to get a pictorial view of your partitions.

Comment: @berndbausch this is what I thought I should've done: use gparted. Is there any recommended arguments/configs, considering I've used resize2fs? Can you tell me the command line you'd use, considering home is mounted at /dev/sda1?

Comment: gparted is an interactive tool. Regarding command-line parameters, the main difficulty is calculating the size and last sector of the new partition. See the answer for that.

Answer (score 4):

First, the usual warning: back up your data. Resizing partitions and file systems is never a 100% safe operation.

If a graphical environment with GParted is available to you, the simplest solution is to:

1. re-grow the `/dev/sda1` partition to the size of the file system it contains: right-click on it, select "Check" and apply all operations; then
2. shrink the partition to the desired size: right-click on it, select "Resize/Move", set the desired "New size", confirm and apply all operations; GParted takes care of resizing the file system too.

Alternatively, using command line tools, you can use `dumpe2fs` or `tune2fs` to get the file system's block size and block count and re-create the to-shrink partition, making the new one start at the same byte the original one did and end at that offset plus the size (in bytes) of the shrunk file system.

Here is a complete example that can be used to play around with the relevant commands, using GNU `parted` and a loop device backed by a regular file:

- We first create a block device, partition it and create a 210 MiB file system on the first (and only) partition:

  ```
  $ fallocate -l 211MiB testfile
  $ sudo losetup -f testfile
  $ sudo parted /dev/loop0 unit MiB mklabel msdos mkpart primary 1 100%FREE
  $ lsblk /dev/loop0
  NAME      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
  loop0       7:0    0  211M  0 loop 
  └─loop0p1 259:0    0  210M  0 part
  $ sudo mkfs.ext4 -L test -v /dev/loop0p1 210M
  $ sudo mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/temp
  $ df /mnt/temp
  Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
  /dev/loop0p1      202353    14    187491   1% /mnt/temp
  ```
- Then we resize the file system to 150 MiB, ending up in a state analogous to the one described in your question:

  ```
  $ sudo umount /mnt/temp
  $ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/loop0p1
  $ sudo resize2fs /dev/loop0p1 150M
  $ sudo mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/temp
  $ df /mnt/temp
  Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
  /dev/loop0p1      144716  1550    132414   2% /mnt/temp
  $ sudo umount /mnt/temp
  ```
- Now we get the target size for the partition, based on the current size of the file system it hosts:

  ```
  $ sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/loop0p1
  ```

  or

  ```
  $ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/loop0p1
  ```

  where the relevant lines are:

  ```
  Block count:              153600
  First block:              1
  Block size:               1024
  ```

  allowing us to compute the new partition size, in bytes, as:

  ```
  153600 * 1024 = 157286400
  ```

  We then need the current starting byte of the partition (pretending we do not already know it):

  ```
  $ sudo parted /dev/loop0 unit b print
  Number  Start     End         Size        Type     File system  Flags
   1      1048576B  221249535B  220200960B  primary  ext4
  ```

  and we now know that the new partition will start at byte 1048576 and end at byte

  ```
  1048576 + 157286400 -1 = 158334975
  ```

  Note that `parted` counts starting from 0 and uses inclusive intervals; hence, one byte has to be subtracted from the partition's size to compute its ending byte.

  We can now re-create the partition and check the result:

  ```
  $ sudo parted /dev/loop0 unit b rm 1 mkpart primary 1048576 158334975
  $ lsblk /dev/loop0
  NAME      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
  loop0       7:0    0  211M  0 loop 
  └─loop0p1 259:0    0  150M  0 part
  ```

  Running `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/loop0p1` anew will then alert you if you happened to shrink the partition too much, allowing you to fix it before damaging your file system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try it, as soon as I get my hands on a drive that I can store my backups.

Comment: @surfboardcompound I added a simpler alternative based on GParted, in case it's available to you.

Answer (score 0):

You known after shrink fs,
　have to calculate new partition size & resize partition table.
　And mbr / gpt partition table..

If don't have command line hobby, do it in GUI is easy:

### gnome-disk-utility

[image: gnome-disk-unitily_resize.png]

### gparted

[image: gparted_resize.png]

Especially, `gparted` also show fs size (if it not equal to part size)

[image: gparted_info]