# dd: No space left on device

Tags: command-line, dd

I was restoring a backup of my Raspberry Pi on a new micro SD card.
The original card was 16Gb and the destination card was 16Gb, too. However, during the transfer `dd` complained that there isn't any space left.
Now, I know that every card has a different real size, but how can I fix that? Is it possible to "chop" off few bytes and make the disk image fit in the card?

Comment: `dd` is not a good tool to backup, there may be data at the end of the image. You could get a bigger SD, and not do this again. instead use tar. You can also mount the image in your desktop Gnu/Linux, and create a tar from it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it, maybe in an answer? How could I prime a raw disk from a tar archive?

Comment: You would have to create the file-system, mount it, then un-tar into it. However there is a bit more to it for the PI (partitioning, and boot file-system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can "chop" bytes off a raw disk image file using `truncate`.

```
truncate -s 15G image.raw
```

Obviously, this will affect the data within the disk image. You probably want to shrink the contained filesystems so they are not truncated along the way. `gparted` is a tool with nice UI to achieve this.

```
gparted image.raw
```

Just shrink and move partitions until there is enough "unallocated space" at the end of the disk. If your disks partitions are defined in the MBR, you are done at this point. If a GPT is used, you need to leave a few bytes more and re-generate the secondary GPT after truncating.

[How do I resize a disk image device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71892/how-do-i-resize-a-disk-image-device?rq=1) is somewhat related.

Comment: This answer is almost perfect, for anyone interested in further details, I'd suggest to take a look at https://superuser.com/a/1170779/83585 , since there's the full list of commands to use (gparted can't read directly from the file, you have to mount it first)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, storage media of "same size" (16GB in your case) do not necessarily have the exact same number of bytes. There can be some small differences depending on brands.

If you cloned your whole card storage to a card having more capacity (few bytes more in your case), with a command like: `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc` (where `sdb` is your source and `sdc` your backup), then its perfectly normal that when restoring back with the opposite command `dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdb` (assuming that drives are listed in same order) `dd` will complain that there is no more space left.

Simply the remaining unused bytes at the end of your backup (`sdc`) could not be copied to the smaller `sdb` card, but your original storage was fully restored.
So, why would be it needed to "fix" it?

Unless your need to truly minimize risks, you could possibly directly physically replace your original card by its backup, but don't forget to backup it again soon.

Comment: That `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc` is a terrible command to use: you're writing each block on the SD card potentially eight times. Just use `cat /dev/sdb >/dev/sdc` (to overwrite `/dev/sdc`)

Comment: The OP mentioned he was using `dd`, hence my answer with this command. I am also regularly using the command that you mentions. However, something that I appreciate with `dd` is the `conv=sync,noerror` option and  the possibility to know the percentage cloned with `status=progress`.

Comment: That's even worse - if `dd` gets a read error (even a transient one) it can actually corrupt your output data with the flags, `conv=sync,noerror`